# WordPress set post terms and - add action - save post issue

Tags: wordpress, function, variables

Trying to set custom taxonomy terms to posts via the add action (save post) hook

here's my code

```
function dosomething(){

global $post, $wpdb;
$id = $post->ID;
global $id; // using id somewhere else 
$cat_ids = array( 45,35 ); // will be vars at somepoint in the future 

wp_set_post_terms( $id , $cat_ids, 'OriginalTag'); 
}

add_action('save_post', 'dosomething',10); // this will run the function on page load
```

This does not work for me? but via trial and error I found that, if I replace $id in the set_post_terms function with the actual value of the post like this:

```
wp_set_post_terms( 2154 , $cat_ids, 'OriginalTag'); //2154 being the post ID
```

everything works fine... :/ cant figure out what I'm doing wrong here

p.s. I've echoed $id and it does return the correct value

Answer (score 0):

```
function dosomething($id){
    $cat_ids = array( 290, 44 ); // will be vars at somepoint in the future
    wp_set_post_terms( $id , $cat_ids, 'post_tag');
}

add_action('save_post', 'dosomething', 10, 1); // this will run the function on page load
```

This worked for me, obviously I've substituted tag ids of my own and using the default taxonomy so put your own back in. I'm passing the `$id` of the new post through the action call, not with globals which didn't work for me either.